# Tax Calculation in Magento 1 | Should be 20% | Not 20%

Tags: magento, calculation, invoice, tax

We are exporting Magento orders to another platform and have noticed what seems to be a major issue in the tax calculation; hoping you guys can help..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABOjX.png)

In the example above; we have a shipping fee £6.95 (inc tax), a discount £5.80 and a product sales price of £116 (inc tax).

Total Inc. Tax is correct:
(£116 + £6.95) - (£5.80) = £117.15.

The Tax charged however is showing as £19.53 which I just can't replicate..

I've tried:

- 20% of £116 = £23.2
- 20% of £116 - £5.80 = £22.04

No permutation seems to deliver amount of tax charged that Magento is stating: £19.53

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

These figures are tax inclusive:

[image: tax inclusive]

So convert them to tax exclusive by dividing by `1.2`.

```
96.667
5.792
-4.833
```

Now that adds up to `97.625`. `20%` of that is `19.525` which needs to be rounded up to `19.53`. The government wants all the half pence amounts!

The original tax inclusive amounts added to `117.15` so subtract the tax and you get a pre-tax amount of `97.62`.

Comment: Thanks you so much!! 

That really eluded me earlier - very much appreciated!